# How to help my Solr engine to understand related terms?

Tags: solr

I have a big list of related terms (not synonyms) that I would like my solr engine to take into account when searching. For example:

Database --> PostgreSQL, Oracle, Derby, MySQL, MSSQL, RabbitMQ, MongoDB

For this kind of list, I would like Solr to take into account that if a user is searching for "postgresql configuration" he might also bring results related to "RabbitMQ" or "Oracle", but not as absolute synonyms. Just to boost results that have these keywords/terms.
What is the best approach to implement such connection? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've already discovered that these are synonyms - and that you want to use that metainformation as a boost (which is a good idea).

The key is then to define a field that does what you want - *in addition* to your regular field. Most of these cases are implemented by having a second field that does the "less accurate" version of the field, and apply a lower boost to matches in that field compared to the accurate version.

You define both fields - one with synonyms (for example `content_synonyms`) and one without (`content`), and then add a `copyField` instruction from the `content` field (this means that Solr will take anything submitted to the `content` field and "copy" it as the source text for the `content_synonyms` field as well.

Using `edismax` you can then use `qf` to query both fields and give a higher weight to the exact content field: `qf=content^10 content_synonyms` will score hits in `content` 10x higher than hits in `content_synonyms`, in effect using the synonym field for boosting content.

The exact weights will have to be adjusted to fit your use case, document profile and query profile.

Comment: I don't fully understand. by this approach, when I query the phrase "PostgreSQL configuration" for example, what would be different between the two fields I'm querying over (content and content_synonyms) beside the different weights in the qf? Meaning, I don't understand where the synonyms themselves comes into place. Thanks.

Comment: The synonyms would only be present in the `content_synonyms` field. The analysis chain would be different for the fields, with only the `content_synonyms` field expanding synonyms for terms. That way the `content` field does not contain synonyms, so hits in that field will only match the exact query (so if you query `Database` and the content contains `MySQL`, the `content` field won't match, but `content_synonyms` will). If you have a document that contains `Database`, it will create a match in the `content` field and be scored 10x higher than the hit in `content_synonyms`.